# How to replace strings in sentence with appropriate dictionary values?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows :

```
dict_ = { 
        'the school in USA' : 'some_text_1',
        'school' : 'some_text_1',
        'the holy church in brisbane' : 'some_text_2',
        'holy church' : 'some_text_2'
}
```

and a list of sentences as follows :

```
text_sent = ["Ram is going to the holy church in brisbane",\
             "John is going to holy church", \
             "shena is going to the school in USA", \
             "Jennifer is going to the school"]
```

I want to replace the occurrences of keys of dict_ dictionary with corresponding values in text_sent. I did this as follows :

```
for ind, text in enumerate(text_sent) :
    for iterator in dict_.keys() :
        if iterator in text : 
            text_sent[ind] = re.sub(iterator, dict_[iterator], text)

for i in text_sent:
    print(i)
```

Output I got is as follows :

```
Ram is going to the some_text_2 in brisbane
John is going to some_text_2
shena is going to the some_text_1 in USA
Jennifer is going to the some_text_1
```

Expected output is :

```
Ram is going to some_text_2
John is going to some_text_2
shena is going to some_text_1
Jennifer is going to some_text_1
```

What I need is, the strings that are longer (for example, "*the holy church in brisbane*") need to be replaced, if in case, the complete string is not available in the sentence, only then the smaller version(for example, '*holy church*')  should be used instead of the longer one for replacing corresponding value in text_sent's sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to make the replacements, using `str.join` to format the regex expression from the substring dictionary:

```
import re
d = {'the school in USA': 'some_text_1', 'school': 'some_text_1', 'the holy church in brisbane': 'some_text_2', 'holy church': 'some_text_2'}
text_sent = ["Ram is going to the holy church in brisbane",\
         "John is going to holy church", \
         "shena is going to the School in USA", \
         "Jennifer is going to the school"]

r = [re.sub('|'.join(d), lambda x:d[x.group()], i, re.I) for i in text_sent]
```

Output:

```
['Ram is going to some_text_2', 'John is going to some_text_2', 'shena is going to some_text_1', 'Jennifer is going to the some_text_1']
```

Comment: I am a beginner level programmer. Could you please explain how exactly d[x.group()] would work ?

Comment: @rishikeshfulari When the regex expression finds a match, the `re.sub` function provides access to the matched value via a parameter of a `lambda` function. `lambda x:d[x.group()]` is called when a match is found, and `d[x.group()]` looks up the match in `d` and returns its value.

Comment: If I changed the case of 'school' to 'School' in "shena is going to the school in USA", it fails to replace it. Can you suggest changes in this code to make the comparison insensitive to case? I can't convert the case of the complete sentence to lower() as we need to preserve the case of other words. But, the program should be able to change the case of a word in the sentence if the corresponding key exists in the dictionary with different case.

Comment: @rishikeshfulari Please see my recent edit. The `re.I` flag can be used to ignore the case of the matched text.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **auxiliary list** for the dict and sort it dependending on it's elements length.

```
dict_ = {'the school in USA' : 'some_text_1',
         'school' : 'some_text_1',
         'the holy church in brisbane' : 'some_text_2',
         'holy church' : 'some_text_2'}

text_sent = ["Ram is going to the holy church in brisbane",
             "John is going to holy church",
             "shena is going to the school in USA",
             "Jennifer is going to the school"]

dict_keys = list(dict_.keys())
dict_keys.sort(key=len)
dict_keys.reverse()

text_sent_replaced = []
for text in text_sent:
    modified_text = text
    for key in dict_:
        modified_text = modified_text.replace(key,dict_[key])
    text_sent_replaced.append(modified_text)

print(text_sent_replaced)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you didn't add a `break` statement. You are overriding values if there are multiple matches later on in the `dict_` dictionary. Try this:

```
for ind, text in enumerate(text_sent) :
    for iterator in dict_.keys() :
        if iterator in text :
            text_sent[ind] = re.sub(iterator, dict_[iterator], text)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish the task without using re as long as the substituted elemets are at the end of each line, as was the case in your example:

```
for ind, text in enumerate(text_sent) :
    for iterator in dict_.keys() :
        if iterator in text :
            text_sent[ind] = text.split(iterator)[0] + dict_[iterator]

for i in text_sent:
    print(i)

#Prints:
#Ram is going to the some_text_2
#John is going to some_text_2
#shena is going to the some_text_1
#Jennifer is going to the some_text_1
```